# Python zlib module error when decompressing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compression, zlib

A few days ago I wrote a python program to compress some Html data and insert into a database. I compressed them using zlib.

```py
html = "<html><head><title>Title</title></head><body><p>Paragraph</p></body></html>"
compressed_html = str(zlib.compress(html.encode('utf-8'))).replace('b\'', '').replace('\'', '')
```

Then the compressed_html variable is something like,

`x\\x9c\\xd4\\xbd\\xfbv\\xdb\\xb6\\xb30\\xfa\\x7f\\xd6\\xfa\\xde...`

Today now I tried to uncompress them like this.

```py
html = html.encode('utf-8')
# html is retrieved from database.
# html is like now b'x\\x9c\\xd4\\xbd\\xfbv\\xdb\\xb6\\xb30\\xfa\\x7f\\xd6\\xfa\\xde...'
decompressed = zlib.decompress(html)
```

This throws an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/Sakith Karunasena/PycharmProjects/Twibot Repairer/main.py", line 16, in
>
> decompressed = zlib.decompress(html)
>
> zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check

Comment: you would have to put back b\' and \' which you removed - and then you will have data which you can decompress.

Comment: @furas How? Example, please.

Comment: frankly, you can't put it back - you shouldn't remove them.

Comment: You can't just remove parts of the compressed data and expect it to decompress. If you can't recreate where those parts where and put them back in, your data is corrupted. Next time test compression and decompression before you rely on it to keep data for several days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compress it use this

```
compressed_html = zlib.compress(html.encode(), level=6)
```

level can between -1 to 9 based on compression ratio required [here](https://stackabuse.com/python-zlib-library-tutorial/)

To store it:

```
with open('filename.txt','wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write(compressed_html)
```

To read it

```
with open('filename.txt','rb') as infile:
    compressed_html = infile.read()
```

To decompress back

```
decompressed_html = zlib.decompress(compressed_html).decode()
```